# Where does the imaginary part of a singnal come from?

Tags: sampling, complex, quadrature

So I recently watched [this](https://greatscottgadgets.com/sdr/7/) lovely overview of DSP/SDR explaining how demodulation of AM and FM becomes trivial by turning a signal into a complex number. (AM being the magnitude of the number and FM being the phase angle difference between two samples).

But I'm still confused. It's simply transferring the problem to "How do you get the envelope of a signal" to "how do you represent the signal in 2d". Where does this imaginary component come from?

The guy says to get the envelope of an AM waveform you need only one sample. And while you already are in the complex plane, yes. Sure. Get the magnitude of that one complex number. But a sample, as far as I understood, is a real value. For example a power measurement from a sine wave generator. So you get "0.7V". What's the envelope? It could be anything. Could be a rising edge of the sine, falling edge, a peak, even a valley if you have DC offset. So I call BS you need only one sample.

The person in the video simply glosses over how you actually get the imaginary part? Do you just add a sine wave imaginary component? (sin(t)*i)? Do you phase shift your entire signal by 90° (f(t-tau/4) * i) and add that? Or something else entirely?

Heck I don't even know how to tag this question.

Comment: > "a sample, as far as I understood, is a real value" nope, it's two real values interpreted as complex number.

Comment: and you found the right tag, [tag:quadrature]! Research what a quadrature mixer does, and you'll see, it converts your RF signal to an equivalent complex-valued baseband signal. There's your answer!

Comment: @MarcusMüller When I plop my signal generator into my oscilloscope I get a real value. Because voltage is a real physical size. When I take an audio file and open it in audacity, a sample is a real value. Because the speaker membranes can only move back or forth. If I pop an antenna into my oscilloscope, I get a voltage messurement. A voltage is a real value. If I take one such measurement i call it a sample. If I take a sine graph over time, and pick one value on the sine wave at any particular point, that's a real value and a sample. Of course samples are real values!

Comment: All nice examples, but the samples coming out of your HackRF (or other SDR) are not real samples. Again, **read up on quadrature mixing**.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Okay. My question was how to get from real values (voltage on the antenna) to quadrature samples. I will read up on that topic. The issue I had with the video was. "Well if you do magic trick1 this becomes easy." with no explanation of magic trick1 of what it even means, is or how it works. I am aware that the samples that those tricks work on are not real but complex and that you do indeed just need one of them to get the amplitude envelope for example. But you can prove that you need multiple real(-world) samples to produce that one complex sample.

Comment: Don't overthink it.  Any real sample has magnitude, and phase (phase relative to what you ask?)  Typically you multiply a real signal set with a complex carrier - complex being real and a 90 degree phase lagged imaginary number.  This has the effect of basebanding.  One real sample ends as one complex sample.  A DC baseband real value is magnitude with zero "relative" phase.  Complex values are just samples with magnitude and relative phase

Comment: @FalcoGer: When you look at the _voltage_ only, which your oscilloscope does, you get a real value. If you look at current, you get a different real value. The two are however closely linked, and it can be advantageous to treat them as one complex number. Similarly, EM fields are another physical manifestation of two interlinked real quantities.

Comment: Similarly in sound waves there is a concept of air pressure and particle displacement which if memory serves are offset by 90 degrees in a medium with a real-valued specific acoustic impedance like open air. Sampling two channels allows you to sample at half the rate because that additional axis allows negative frequencies to become unambiguous. See: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/672/complex-sampling-can-break-nyquist