# What should be IQ sample rate at least?

Tags: sampling, nyquist, downsampling

As i read, IQ sample doesn't need nyquist criteria. What is the mathematical representation of this result? Why IQ sample doesn't need nyquist frequency? I know that can be set to nyquist frequency but i want to know why not equal nyquist frequency at least.

Thanks for answers..

Comment: Your question is based on a misunderstanding. It *does* require Nyquist rate sampling.

Comment: Nyquist rate means twice of max frequency component. As i read IQ sample doesn't require nyquist frequency, also recommended IQRate=1.25*fmax. Why?

Comment: "Nyquist rate means twice of max frequency component" the answer you've gotten explains why that is *wrong* for complex sampling.

Comment: Please ckeck the answer dear: https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000kIpTSAU&l=en-TR

Comment: I did. It doesn't contradict what I said. Again, the answer you've gotten addresses your misunderstanding about Nyquist rate for complex sampling.

Comment: Do you have any document that is  explain to Nyquist criteria for IQ signal in therotical?

Comment: hm, my signals and systems textbook did in university. Where do *you* know Nyquist from? Other than that, Oppenheim's standard "Discrete-time signal processing" book introduces Nyquist for real-valued signals first, but makes the explanation super graphical so that someone understanding complex signals don't have symmetric spectra sees the factor of 2 disappears.

Comment: I saw it during my university years but not complex signal. Complex signal sampling  confused me, actually i know very well what is nyquist(For not aliasing due to negative frequencies) but i don't understand why IQ signals don't have negative frequencies.Also my english is not good ,sorry:)

Comment: They *have* negative frequencies. They can just represent separate things on negative and positive frequencies, which real signals can't.

Comment: I will work on this issue, thank you dear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marcus commented, it certainly does follow the Nyquist criterion. However you just need to keep in mind that I/q sampling is complex so each complex sample can be considered 2 real independent samples and Nyquist will still apply. Also take a look at this answer ["Complex sampling" can break Nyquist?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/672/complex-sampling-can-break-nyquist)

Comment: I know IQ component, nyquist frequency means twice of max frequency component. IQ sample doesn't require nyquist frequency, can be lower than nyquist frequency. Why?

Comment: "nyquist frequency means twice of max frequency component." No. Read the link.

Comment: Probably  you didn't share link, can you share me?

Comment: The link in the answer.