# Why is the bandwidth of each ZigBee channel in the 2.4GHz frequency band 2MHz, while the sampling interval of the ZigBee receiver is 0.5us?

Tags: sampling, nyquist, bandwidth

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zigbee#Radio_hardware), the [XBee paper](https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10076615), the [BlueBee paper](https://cs.gmu.edu/%7Esong/paper/SenSys17_Wenchao.pdf), and the [WeBee paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3117811.3117816), I learned that:

1. In the 2.4 GHz band, the bandwidth of each ZigBee channel is 2 MHz.
2. For receiving a signal over one of these channels, a ZigBee receiver should sample the signal with a sampling interval $T_{s} = 0.5 \mu s$.

However, according to [Nyquist's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency), the sampling frequency $f_{s} = 1/T_{s}$ of a ZigBee receiver should be twice ZigBee's signal bandwidth. Hence, the ZigBee's single-channel bandwidth should be $2 \times f_{s} = 2 / T_{s} = 4$ MHz, which contradicts what I learned.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/672/complex-sampling-can-break-nyquist

Comment: @AlexTP Yes! Thank you very much.

Comment: So lets close the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Zigbee is primarily designed to be cheap, not fast or efficient. Maximum data rate is 250kb/s so 2 MHz sample rate is more than enough to capture any data signal.

The "2MHz bandwidth" number mainly refers to the RF channel layout. Zigbee channels are 2 MHz wide and spaced 5 MHz apart. This primarily determines what RF filtering needs to happen to prevent interference between adjacent channels. Here, again, there is plenty of margin, to make practical implementations as inexpensive as possible (at the expense of wasting a lot of potential bandwidth).