# How does the quadrature sampling lower the sampling rate?

Tags: sampling, quadrature

According to [this tutorial](https://dspguru.com/files/QuadSignals.pdf), by exploiting quadrature sampling with IQ signals, we then have the benefit that each ADC operates at half the sampling rate of standard real-signal sampling (This conclusion in the link is right below the Figure. 18). Why is that? It seems the bandwidth of the signal is the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Complex sampling" can break Nyquist?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/672/complex-sampling-can-break-nyquist)

Answer (score 2):

Let’s say you wanted to sample an analog bandpass signal whose bandwidth is 1 Mhz. Using a single A/D converter, to avoid aliasing errors you would have to sample that analog bandpass signal at a sample rate of just a bit greater than 2 MHz (2 megasamples/second). In quadrature sampling using two A/D converters (the top portion of Figure 14), to avoid aliasing errors each converter would operate at a sample rate of just a bit greater than 1 MHz (1 megasamples/second).

Comment: Thanks! So the benefit of quadrature sampling basically is allowing us to sample with  a sample rate just a bit greater than the signal band but not twice of it as the bandpass sampling requires?